# How to increase maximum number of sidebars support?

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

How can i use more than 20 sidebars in wordpress. I'm working on a big information portal, and I need big amaunt of sidebars (about 40, I guess).
So I have 20 sidebars now and when I add one more it overrides one of the previous entered. 
I searched the web about similar problems, but I found nothing ...
Can somebody help me get out of this situation?

[Link](http://ideas4web.eu/sedmicata.com/) to the site

Comment: That should not happen. Are you using `register_sidebars()` with a fixed number as first argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried it on a test install with twenty-something sidebars, all works fine. Note that `id` parameter should be unique between all of them. `name` doesn't have to be, but it's nice to keep it unique as well so as to avoid confusion in the admin UI.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'twenty-three',
    'id' => 'sidebar-23',
    'description' => 'dummy description',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>'
) );
```

Comment: It is unique ... Just tried on a fresh install and not work with my theme :( If there is some issue with themes ?

Comment: Possibly, because it works on the twentytwelve theme.

Comment: I can't believe ... It is working now. All the day it didn't work, and now it's working. I dont know how. I was just waiting for help here. I'll accept your answer because it is correct. ;)